# Spring Kafka with Dynamic @KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.x with **spring-kafka** (not **spring-integration-kafka**)

I have multiple beans annotated with `@KafkaListener` ... each one consuming from one topic... so since I have 12 topics then I also need to have 12 KafkaConsumers beans ... and I would like to know if I can create those beans programmatically / dynamically  ... maybe using **KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry** in order to create consumer containers dynamically.

Note: I need to consume messages in batch ... so maybe I can use **BatchMessageListener**?

Current code:

```
@KafkaListener(
        id = COUNTRY,
        containerFactory = KAFKA_LISTENER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME,
        topics = {TOPIC},
        groupId = GROUP_ID,
        clientIdPrefix = CLIENT_ID,
        errorHandler = VALIDATION_ERROR_HANDLER_BEAN_NAME
    )
    @Override
    public void consume(final List<MessageDTO> messages,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) final List<String> topics,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) final List<String> messagesKey,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) final List<Integer> partitionIds,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) final List<Long> timestamps,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) final List<Long> offsets) {
            (...)
    }
```

Each topic consumer has its own implementation depending on the topic. Can you guys point me to a blog/pseudocode/git thread/answer, please?

Comment: every topic is in same cluster? and what about payloads? are they different?

Comment: The payload structure is the same ... and I have one topic per country. And then I will have at least one consumer per topic because the implementation depends on the country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBean-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Supplier-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer...-

Create your object and register it as a bean providing it via the Supplier in the above method. Spring will run the bean post processors necessary to set everything up.

Comment: as discussed on other channels => https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1059

Answer (score 0):

If your topics are having some pattern you can try this one also:

```
      kafka:
        bindings:
            input.consumer.destination-is-pattern: true
```

Comment: That's only for Spring Cloud Stream; when using `@KafkaListener` you would use the `topicPattern` annotation property.